# RSS reader for Windows with 2 panes that synchronizes with Tiny Tiny RSS

Tags: windows, rss

I'm looking for the *perfect* RSS Feed reader for my own use.

Stuff I need:

- it needs to run on Windows - I run 7 and 8, so those definitely
- a 2-pane (not a 3-pane view) - with feeds on the left side, and the full article on the right (like [Akregator](https://userbase.kde.org/Akregator) or [Sputnik](https://macdownload.informer.com/sputnik/download))
- I'd like it to be able to view links of articles in tabs, so I don't need to switch to a browser
- I need it to synchronize with Tiny Tiny RSS(TT-RSS) 
  (I run my own instance, and I have my mobile client sync with it
  already.)
- it *absolutely positively* must hide unread feeds - I'd be running Sputnik portably rather than TT-RSS if not for that

It’s a bit subjective, but I need it to be reliable as well - something that is unsupported, and crashes every 5 minutes is not cool.

I do *not* want a browser extension - I need something reliable and standalone, and these are the *minimum* criteria I need - I'm looking for something that is an improvement from my current workflow of using Firefox and a TT-RSS instance on a website, and this would be what I need to integrate and improve on it.